# Setting up a vagrant box from an existing vm

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to set up a box from an existing vm.  I started by mostly following the instructions at https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one. But I didn't want to lose my original vm, so I skipped that part and I created a new dir with a new Vagrant file.  `vagrant up` brings up a vm OK, but it can't connect.  I was able to get in on the console. The second net adapter had the same ip as the original vm, even though I set it differently in the Vagrant file.  I changed the ip of that adapter and now I can ssh in. Any ideas on how I can get vagrant to handle the ips correctly to begin with?  Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a known problem, discussed in https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5186

Answer (score 0):

Setting `config.ssh.private_key_path` worked for me.